# DBeaver is failing to execute any on SQLite. "[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database"

Tags: sqlite, dbeaver

I'm trying to use DBeaver to manipulate an SQLite database and, pretty much any operation I try on the database schema, like creating a table or column, it fails with:

```
SQL Error [1]: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near ")": syntax error)
  [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near ")": syntax error)
```

Do you have any idea on how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Assuming you haven't solved it, yet: it would help if you would provide more information on what you are actually doing? What is the simplest example you have that fails? In most cases these errors are related to syntax errors in your SQL statement. And if you have solved it: what was the problem and the solution?
I would advise to read: [ask questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you have more than one Database Connection.

You need to go to the database "SQL Editor" > "Set active connection"

[image]